# How to read columns starting with single quotes and write to other cells without losing the Excel cell formatting using xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

Im struggling to get xlwings read and write a range(column values) without losing the formatting of the cells in a macro enabled excel file (.xlsm).
Either im losing formatting in some columns or formatting is preserved but I lose the starting single quote "'" in both cases.(I have many cell values starting with a single quote like `'abc'`, `'Y'` etc which is lost during copying)
This is the following snippet I used to copy value from one column to another on all sheets:-

```
for i in range(1,len(names)):

                sheet.range((colnamelRow+1,colnameCol+i),(sheet.api.UsedRange.Row +sheet.api.UsedRange.Rows.Count,colnameCol+i)).value = sheet.range((colnamelRow+1,colnameCol),(sheet.api.UsedRange.Row + sheet.api.UsedRange.Rows.Count,colnameCol)).options(ndim=2).value
```

Comment: The `range` object has a `copy` and `paste` method: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range.copy and https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range.paste. You can use them to preserve the formatting.

Comment: I tried using `api.copy` and `api.paste` and it didn't work, code runs forever

Comment: Then you should post the code you were using.

Comment: The one I gave added that's the code I'm using just instead of `.value` I had put `.api.copy` on Left and `.api.paste` ojnthe right

Comment: everything where you use `.api` is supported natively by xlwings, so no need for this.

Comment: It says `range`object doesn't have `PasteSpecial` an I doing anything wrong here

Comment: I tried using `.api.copy` and the code ran forever and when I used without the `.api` and `.paste`  the code ran but values were not pasted and when I tried to use `.PasteSpecial` it says `range` object doesn't have this attribute, is the copy paste no longer working in the lattest `xlwings`